# How to get the keys as string array from reflect MapKeys?

Tags: go, reflection

I need to use `strings.Join(invoicesBatch, ",")` to join a string array.

But the array I got from the map using `reflect.ValueOf(invoiceList).MapKeys()` is `reflect.Value` array. Is there a easy way to convert them into a string array.

The map was initialized with string key.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to use loop but you won't need to create a new slice every time as we already know the length. Example:

```
func main() {
    a := map[string]int{
        "A": 1, "B": 2,
    }
    keys := reflect.ValueOf(a).MapKeys()
    strkeys := make([]string, len(keys))
    for i := 0; i < len(keys); i++ {
        strkeys[i] = keys[i].String()
    }
    fmt.Print(strings.Join(strkeys, ","))
}
```

Comment: I hope there is no way other than this

Comment: It seems that this approach works better then @zola's proposal. Though as a Python developer, I am a bit surprised that we need to use reflection to get dictionary keys :)

Comment: Using reflect for this is completely unnecessary.  See answer below for a better method.

Answer (score 42):

instead of using reflection you can use a for loop and range to get a slice of keys like this

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
)

func main() {
  data := map[string]int{
      "A": 1,
      "B": 2,
  }
  keys := make([]string, 0, len(data))
  for key := range data {
    keys = append(keys, key)
  }

  fmt.Print(strings.Join(keys, ","))
}
```

Comment: `keys := make([]string, 0, len(data))`, otherwise you'll have commas at the beginning of the result string.

Comment: no need for  key ,_      key := range data is cleaner